# JLabel not displaying on JFrame but only on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, joptionpane

I'm receiving a buffered image as byte[] but when I update the icon of JLabel nothing changes on JFrame even revalidating both JFrame and JLabel.
Instead, when I try to show the JLabel in a JOptionPane it works fine.
I don't understand why.
Here is the code :

```
public class ScreenMonitorServer extends JFrame
{
private String botIPAddress;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket botSocket;
private JLabel screen;

public ScreenMonitorServer(String botIPAddress)
{
    super(botIPAddress+" - Screen Monitor");
    this.botIPAddress=botIPAddress; 
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    screen=new JLabel();
    add(screen);
    setVisible(true);
    try
    {
        serverSocket=new ServerSocket(54323);
        do
            botSocket=serverSocket.accept();
        while(!botSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals(botIPAddress));
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(botSocket.getInputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            BufferedImage image;
            InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])ois.readObject());
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert=ImageIO.read(in);
            ImageIcon screenImage=new ImageIcon(bImageFromConvert);
            setSize(bImageFromConvert.getWidth(),bImageFromConvert.getHeight());
            screen.setIcon(screenImage); //black screen
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,screen);  //works fine
        }
    }   
    catch(IOException exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException exc)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All Swing component can have just one parent component, so when you call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,screen);` you ovveride previous parent and your `JLabel` remove from `ScreenMonitorServer`.

Read [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/swing-135905.html#gdleb).

You need to use two instance of `JLabel` in that case.

Comment: I used the JOptionPane as a test, even without calling  `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,screen);` it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any exception? Do you try to debug. Also calling `while(true)` in `EDT` isn't good idea, may be in your case you block `EDT`.

Comment: This part of your code also make som alarm bells go ringin' in my head: catch(ClassNotFoundException exc)
    {

    }

Comment: @alex2410 No exception is called. I will try but it doesn't seem to be blocked because I added a println and is called each second as the client send the byte[].

Comment: I did not display anything in that catch block because I am casting to byte[] and I don't think it is the problem. However I added a printStackTrace in that block but no exception is caught.

Comment: `println` work in that time but `Event Dispatch Thread` doesn't dispatch GUI events and it hang.

Comment: @Dev01 also try to create label with whitespace `screen=new JLabel(" ");` because empty label haven't size.

Comment: @alex2410 ok I will try but I used a infinite loop because I have to receive data until the client is connected. Any suggestion about how can be changed?

Comment: @Dev01 seems you need to use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), also read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @alex2410 Thanks for the help I resolved by placing the infinite loop in an other thread.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by placing the infinite loop in an other thread.
Thanks for the help.